# Can't link a shared library from an x86-64 object from assembly because of PIC

Tags: linker, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm, ld

I'm porting a shared library from 32-bit to 64-bit. It's composed of some assembly (written for NASM) that exports several procedures and a little bit of higher-level C glue code. I'm building on a 64-bit Debian machine with NASM 2.10.01 and GNU ld 2.22.

Having fixed all the push/pop issues (pushing 32-bit parts of registers obviously won't work in 64-bit mode), I've got the object to assemble, but now I'm halted by the linking stage. Here are my command lines - assembly:

`nasm -Ox -dPTC_ARCH=X64 -f elf64 particl.asm -o particlasm.o`

Linking:

`ld -shared -lc -S -melf_x86_64 particlasm.o ptc_highlevel.o -o libparticlasm.so`
(the -lc switch enforces linking the standard C library in - I need some of its functions in the assembly code)

However, the linker fails with the following message:

```
ld: particlasm.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
particlasm.o: could not read symbols: Bad value`
```

I'm aware of why PIC is required on 64-bit systems; thing is, I am indeed using PIC as described in section 9.2 of the [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/). However, it appears to me that NASM is somehow not marking my code as PIC in the ELF symbol table, which causes the linker to protest, and I cannot find any related command-line switches or directives in the
manual to fix this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have, and apart from generating a dozen warnings about absolute addresses that cannot be RIP-relative, it doesn't help the linker problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it! In my case the relocations resulted from:

1) `libc` calls, which I solved by appending `wrt ..plt` to `libc` calls, e.g. `call rand wrt ..plt`,

2) references to constants placed within the code, which needed to change from e.g. `push MASK_RGB` to `push ptr [rel MASK_RGB]` (where `ptr` is my own type that aliases to the native word type for the given platform).

Comment: `push MASK_RGB` pushes an address in NASM, but `push ptr [rel MASK_RGB]` copies data from memory to the stack.  They're not equivalent unless you also changed the definition of `MASK_RGB`, or changed the code to expect a value instead of a pointer.